# vim , trouble with ctrl-] on scandinavian keyboards

Tags: keyboard, vim

I'm trying to set up ctags with Vim. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> is supposed to jump to a tag under the cursor. (issuing a :ta the word works fine)

I'm not sure what to press when using a Swedish keyboard. To get a ], I'll have to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>, however <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> does not work. Any help ?

Here's the keyboard layout:

[image]

Comment: What platform and terminal?

Comment: Fedora 13, gnome-terminal. Or win7 and putty to that same feodra 13 box (or a CentOS 5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following work both in gnome-terminal and in PuTTY, both with the Swedish keyboard layout:

- Ctrl+5: This one comes from xterm, whereby the reasoning appears to be that the octal ASCII code for `^]` is 035 (note the 5), so for example Ctrl+6 is `^^` (036).
- Ctrl+¨ (the key to the right of the **Å**): The even more tenuous reason here is that the US keyboard layout has the **]** in that position.

In Cygwin's [mintty](http://mintty.googlecode.com), your initial idea of Ctrl+AltGr+9 does actually work. It also sends `^]` for the Pause key.

Comment: Ctrl+¨ seems to do the trick